# Regularity for heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the following inhomogeneous heat equation for $f=f(x,t)$ with Neumann boundary conditions on a bounded domain $\Omega$ and initial value $f(x,0)=f_0(x)$:
\begin{align*}
 \partial_t f - \Delta f &= g \quad \text{on } \Omega \times [0,T],
\\
 \nabla f \cdot \hat n &= 0 \quad \text{on } \partial \Omega \times [0,T],
\\
f(0) & = f_0  \quad \text{on } \Omega.
\end{align*}
I am looking for statements of the following form:
If $g, f_0$ and $\Omega$ are smooth enough, then any weak solution $f$ is also a strong solution and has higher regularity.

More precisely, let $k \in \mathbb N_0$. Then under what conditions for $g, f_0$ and $\Omega$ do we obtain that
$$f \in L^2(0,T;H^{2k-2s}( \Omega)) , \; 
\frac{d^s}{dt^s} f \in  L^2(0,T;H^{2k+2-2s}(\Omega))
, \quad s= 0, \ldots,m+1? 
$$

One could assume it is like

- $\Omega$ has $C^k$-boundary
- $\frac{d^s}{dt^s} g \in L^2(0,T; H^{2k-2s}(\Omega))$ for all $s=0,\ldots,k$
- $f_0 \in H^{2k+1}(\Omega)$
- $g,f_0$ satisfy some compatibilty condition.

I cannot find any regularity results to this problem in the literatur; only for the case of Dirichlet boundary condition, see Evans(1997) Thm 6 in Section 7.1 on page 365.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to parts of the problem in a paper of Jan Prüss, 2019

MAXIMAL REGULARITY FOR ABSTRACT PARABOLIC
PROBLEMS WITH INHOMOGENEOUS BOUNDARY DATA
IN $L_p$-SPACES

In a nutshell, we obtain that a right-hand side $g$ in $L^p( \Omega  \times (0,T))$ implies that weak solutions belong to the following Bessel potential spaces
$$
H^1_p(0,T;L^p(\Omega)) \cap L^p(0,T;H^2_p(\Omega)).
$$
For the readers not familiar with the space $H^s_p$ for $s \in \mathbb R$, it has - more or less - equivalent embeddings as the Sobolev space $W^{s,p}$ if $s \in \mathbb N$ and $p \geq 2$.